# Correlating users with one another in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands, amazon-redshift

I am trying to correlate users with one another and assign a common ID for web site visitors.

I have the rows (call it table *a*) `a.UUID, a.seen_time, a.ip_address, a.user_id, a.subdomain`, and I am trying to come up with a `a.matched_id` whereby **if the row IP address is +/- 4hrs of the last** (i.e. continuously), a single `matched_id` is assigned to those rows.

Note that for my purposes, an IP on 2 different subdomains are NOT necessarily the same match, unless they have the same user ID.

Here is the basic process I would follow in a regular programming language (however I need to construct SQL):

- Get the necessary rows of table *a*
- For each row, if any row *ever* has a matching user_id (subdomain doesn't matter), assign them the same `matched_id` (all else being equal, let's use `MIN(uuid)`)
- Partition into subdomain sets.

  For each of those subdomain partitions:

  - Now partition into buckets of IP addresses where each row is < 4hrs from the seen_time before(/after) it (ie on a row-by-row basis)

    For each of those IP address partitions:

    - If any 1 item has a `matched_id` already, assign that to all. Otherwise, assign a new `matched_id` to all (using `MIN(uuid)`). Continue.

I am using Amazon Redshift which is more or less queried the same as Postgres but with a few more limitations (if interested, see [unsupported features](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) and [unsupported functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)): Postgres/ANSI SQL answers accepted.

How can I construct this query in an efficient fashion?

What is the basic SQL process I must follow?

Thanks

**-- UPDATE --**

I have made the following progress shown below:

- I don't know how efficient it is
- I used `discovery_time` instead of `seen_time` as referenced to above, and the table name `mydata` instead of `a`, although its sometimes aliased as `a` and `b`
- It uses an MD5 instead of `MIN(UUID)` since I believe getting that info would require another query - anyway, it doesn't matter too much
- Key problem: It does not count the +/- 4 hrs 'from the last row' instead its as an absolute

Code:

```
--UPDATE mydata m SET matched_id = NULL; --for testing

WITH cte1 AS (
    --start with the max discovery time and go down from there
    --select the matched id if one already exists
    SELECT m.ip, m.subdomain, MAX(m.discovery_time) AS max_discovery_time, 
        CASE WHEN MIN(m.user_id) IS NOT NULL THEN MD5(MIN(m.user_id)) 
        ELSE MIN(m.matched_id) END AS known_matched_id
    FROM mydata m
    GROUP BY m.ip, m.subdomain

    ), cte2 AS (

    SELECT m.uuid, CASE WHEN c.known_matched_id IS NOT NULL THEN c.known_matched_id 
        ELSE MD5(CONCAT(c.ip, c.subdomain, c.max_discovery_time)) END AS matched_id
    FROM mydata m 
    --IP on different subdomains are not necessarily the same match
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN cte1 c ON CONCAT(c.ip, c.subdomain) = CONCAT(m.ip, m.subdomain) 
    WHERE m.discovery_time >= (c.max_discovery_time - INTERVAL '4 hours')
    --Does not work 'row by row' instead in terms of absolutes - need to make this recursive somehow,
    --but Redshift does not support recursive CTEs or user-defined functions
)

UPDATE mydata m
SET matched_id = c.matched_id
FROM cte2 c
WHERE c.uuid = m.uuid;

--view result for an example IP
SELECT m.discovery_time, m.ip, m.matched_id, m.uuid 
FROM mydata m
WHERE m.ip = '12.34.56.78'
ORDER BY m.ip, m.discovery_time;
```

And in case you are wanting to test, the following create script should do you:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata
(
  ip character varying(255),
  subdomain character varying(255),
  matched_id character varying(255),
  user_id character varying(255),
  uuid character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  discovery_time timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT pk_mydata PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);

-- should all get the same matched_id in result, except the 1st
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, '222b5991-9780-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-14 00:03:26');
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, '333b5991-9780-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-16 22:22:26');
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, '379b641b-9782-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-17 03:18:48');
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, 'ac0f6416-977e-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-17 02:53:25');
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, '11fb5991-9780-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-17 03:03:26');
INSERT INTO mydata (ip, subdomain, matched_id, user_id, uuid, discovery_time) VALUES ('12.34.56.78', 'sub1', NULL, NULL, '849d8d61-9781-11e3-9304-127b2ab15ea7', '2014-02-17 03:13:48');
```

The **expected output** would then be for all those rows to be assigned the same `matched_id`, except for the first one (in the INSERT lines) since its time is way more than 4hrs out from the next most recently seen time (and nor does it have a `user_id` to match to any others).

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

- Still not much luck on the continuous row-by-row results. This version seems to work that way if run repeatedly, though
- Interested to make it efficient
- New columns `min_time` and `max_time` denote the min and max times in a 4hr set

Code:

```
-- Set user IDs that are the same 
UPDATE mydata AS m SET matched_id = matching.new_matched_id
FROM (
    SELECT a.user_id, MIN(a.uuid) AS new_matched_id FROM mydata a
    WHERE a.user_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY a.user_id
) AS matching
WHERE m.matched_id IS NULL
AND m.user_id IS NOT NULL
AND matching.user_id = m.user_id;


-- Find rows +/- 4hrs of each other 
-- 1. Set min and max times for a 4hr set --
UPDATE mydata my SET min_time = matching.min_dist, max_time = matching.max_dist, matched_id = new_matched_id
FROM (
    -- mintime is approx
    SELECT a.uuid, MIN(b.matched_id) AS new_matched_id, max(COALESCE(b.min_time, b.discovery_time)) - interval '4 hour' AS min_dist, max(COALESCE(b.max_time, b.discovery_time)) + interval '4 hour' AS max_dist
    FROM mydata a
    JOIN mydata b
    ON (a.ip = b.ip AND a.subdomain = b.subdomain)
    GROUP BY a.uuid
    HAVING ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM max(COALESCE(a.min_time, b.discovery_time)) - a.discovery_time)/3600) <= 4
) matching
WHERE matching.uuid = my.uuid
AND min_time IS NULL;

-- 2. Set the matched id of all the +/- 4hr records --
UPDATE mydata m SET matched_id = new_matched_id, min_time = matching.min_time, max_time = matching.max_time
FROM (
    SELECT a.uuid, MAX(b.min_time) AS min_time, MAX(b.max_time) AS max_time, COALESCE(a.matched_id, MIN(b.uuid)) AS new_matched_id FROM mydata a
    INNER JOIN mydata b
    ON a.ip = b.ip AND a.subdomain = b.subdomain
    WHERE a.discovery_time >= b.min_time
    AND a.discovery_time <= b.max_time
    GROUP BY a.uuid
) matching
WHERE matching.uuid = m.uuid;
```

Comment: Looks like a variant on the islands-gaps problem, wouldn't you say?

Comment: From the redshift link: `Unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints are permitted, but they are informational only. They are not enforced by the system, but they are used by the query planner.` ... well that's another fine mess you got us into...

Comment: @wildplasser haha yep. We can assume that referential integrity is not violated for this problem

Comment: @David having googled the problem your refer to, indeed looks like it might be! Knew someone out there must have done this before me...

Comment: The problem looks a bit like fuzzy relational division: assign users to equivalence groups. I would start by creating a groups table plus a users-to-groups junction table and add rows to these tables. Stepwise; one step for each of the above conditions (if user is not already part of a group). And maybe later combine the complete mess into one very large query.

Comment: Relational division is not trivial in sql. Standard SQL doesn't have very good support for it. Just getting the correct result can take a while and to get the code to run without choking your environment is high level stuff.

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser and David, I have made some progress shown as a question edit. Comments welcome

Comment: Where is table_b? Is it really needed, or can the "subdomain" be derived from table_a in some way?

Comment: @wildplasser unfortunatly not, however for simplicity of the problem and in the sample create script I have removed the extra table

Comment: Could you provide a create-script containing the expected result? Perhaps with a bit bigger dataset.

Comment: In the two tables `a` and `b` you say you need to do a join but there's no column to join on... should there be a `subdomain` column in `a`?

Comment: Sorry you guys asking about table `b`, I have removed it from the problem for simplicity sake. 
Have also clarified the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so but it seems from *whereby if the row IP address is +/- 4hrs of the last* that you need the "last" time for each IP address (or IP + UUID, not sure).  That you get from

```
select ip_address, max(seen_time) group by ip_address
```

You could make a virtual table out of that or use a correlated subquery, see next.

I'm not a Postgres user, but there's surely a function that measures hours.  As a rough sketch,

```
select * from a as A 
where exists (
    select 1 from a 
    where ip_address = A.ip_address
    and   UUID = A.UUID
    group by ip_address, UUID
    having hour(max(seen_time)) - hour(A.seen_time) < 4
)
```

HTH.

Comment: This helps, but from what I can tell it only groups rows into 4hr windows from one row, whereas I need a _continious_ row by row result. For example 3pm entry, 6pm entry and 9pm entry on the same day: I beleive this code would only catch any 2 of those at once, no? I want 1 matched match id for all of them since they are less than 4hrs from the next

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

Add columns for working to your table `a`: `id_1`, `id_2`, `min_time`, `max_time`

Update `id_1` to be the `min(uuid)` for any records with the same `user_id`. Something like this:

```
 -- match any records with a userid
 update a 
 set id_1 = x.uuid 
 from a 
 inner join (   
        select min(uuid) as uuid, userid 
        from a where userid is not null group by userid ) as x
   on a.userId = x.userId
```

Update columns `min_time` and `max_time` to be last_seen minus/plus 4 hours. You could do all this in the next query, but in case you're re-using these values later it'll be more efficient to only calculate once.

```
update a 
set min_time = seen_time - interval '4 hour'
,   max_time = seen_time + interval '4 hour'
```

Join a onto itself, matching records by `ip` and `subdomain`, where `a.seen_time` within 4 hours of the other record. e.g.:

```
update a 
set id_2 = other_uuid
from ( 

    -- join a onto all matching records by ip and subdomain
    -- where a.seen_time within 4 hours of the other record.
    select a.uuid, min(other.uuid) as other_uuid 
    from a 
    inner join a AS other
    on a.ip_address = other.ip_address
    and a.subdomain = other.subdomain
    and a.uuid <> other.uuid
    where a.seen_time > other.min_time
    and a.seen_time < other.max_time
    group by a.uuid
) AS matching 
where a.uuid = matching.uuid
-- no need to match ones already matched on userid
and id_1 is null
```

Now `id_1` and `id_2` combined is what you're looking for.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that this does not work 'row-by-row' because in the 2nd part of code, you have set a constant min and max distance to another row, so the 3rd code snippet would evaluate only other rows in that 8 hour frame, not every row continuously..?